# Show nested collecctions in laravel views

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm new with Laravel , and here is the problem I have
There are 3 tables that have this relations:

AttributeGroup -> one to many-> AttributeGroupMapping

AttributeGroupMapping -> many to one ->  Attribute

I prepared the models and the controllers and I get this collection:

```
lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3093
     all: [
       App\AttributeGroup {#3085
         id: 1,
         name: "General",
         position: 1,
         is_user_defined: 0,
         attribute_family_id: 1,
         created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
         updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
         attributeGroupMapping: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3079
           all: [
             App\AttributeGroupMapping {#3106
               attribute_id: 1,
               attribute_group_id: 1,
               position: 1,
               created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               Attribute: App\Attribute {#3109
                 id: 1,
                 code: "phone1",
                 admin_name: "Phone 1",
                 type: "text",
                 validation: null,
                 position: 1,
                 is_required: 1,
                 is_unique: 0,
                 value_per_locale: 0,
                 value_per_channel: 0,
                 is_filterable: 0,
                 is_configurable: 0,
                 is_user_defined: 0,
                 is_visible_on_front: 0,
                 swatch_type: null,
                 use_in_flat: 1,
                 created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
                 updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               },
             },
             App\AttributeGroupMapping {#3096
               attribute_id: 2,
               attribute_group_id: 1,
               position: 9,
               created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               Attribute: App\Attribute {#3117
                 id: 2,
                 code: "notes",
                 admin_name: "notes",
                 type: "textarea",
                 validation: null,
                 position: 9,
                 is_required: 0,
                 is_unique: 0,
                 value_per_locale: 0,
                 value_per_channel: 0,
                 is_filterable: 0,
                 is_configurable: 0,
                 is_user_defined: 0,
                 is_visible_on_front: 0,
                 swatch_type: null,
                 use_in_flat: 1,
                 created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
                 updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\AttributeGroup {#3077
         id: 2,
         name: "Detalle",
         position: 2,
         is_user_defined: 0,
         attribute_family_id: 1,
         created_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
         updated_at: "2019-11-23 20:46:27",
         attributeGroupMapping: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3070
           all: [],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Now, how can I get to cycle with foreach trow the 3 levels so i can get:
...............AttributeGroup (each one)

........................AttributeMapping (each one)

....................................Attribute (each one)

Here is what i send to the view:

```
$attributesGroups= AttributeGroup::with('attributeGroupMapping.Attribute')->get();
return view('admin.contact-conf', compact('attributesGroups'));
```

How can i make it work?
Thanks

Comment: What do you have on your blade view page? Should have something like `@foreach($items as item) @endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

You can see what you have passed in your view by `dd(attributesGroups)` anyway I think following code will work in your view:

```
@foreach ($attributesGroups as $attributesGroup)
        <p>{{$attributesGroup->name}}<p>
        @foreach ($attributesGroup->attributeGroupMapping as $attributeGroupMappingItem)
            <p>{{$attributeGroupMappingItem->Attribute->code}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: need double brace.

Comment: That solution ony shows one code, but if the mapping has more than one is the problem

Comment: @Pablo what do you mean of mapping? attributeGroupMapping? there is `foreach` per each attributeGroupMapping items